# Why *.egg-info are uploaded after python package build

Tags: python

i'm running `python3 setup.py sdist` which simply suppose to creates distribution package in dist folder. I don't understand where and why egg_info is coming in my package? what is the importance ?

Answer (score 0):

`egg_info` is package metadata. It stores data about your package, like its name, version, and dependencies. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0376/ is a newer standard that uses *.dist-info directories.